# Proper class of operations

Tags: abstract-algebra, products, binary-operations, semigroup-homomorphism

Usually, a collection of operations forms a set.
But I've heard of an example where it is (must be) a proper class.
Namely, that

$\mathbb{CompHauss}$

becomes a variety if proper class of operations is allowed.
What are the operations? I have heard of ultrafilter convergences, but I do not know what they technically are. Why small set of them doesn't yield that
$\mathbb{CompHauss}$ is a variety?

BTW, how the **smallness** of the collection of operations is used in the proof
of Birkhoff's type theorem on $HSP$ being the variety?

Comment: Compact Haussdorf spaces are the algebras for the *ultrafilter* monad $Set\to Set$ (sending $X$ to $\{$ultrafilters on $X\}$

Comment: Yes, that is a good description, however I do not know how the operations work.I have now the set of all ultrafilters on X, What reasoning comes next?